# How to check if two shapes in a binary image are similar in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two binary images, each of which have a single white filled parallelogram and a black background. The only difference between the two images is that the parallelograms are in different locations and are slightly different from one another in shape. All the parameters between the two images are the same except for that one change.

I want to check how similar the shape of the two parallelograms are, by using some sort of comparing measure.

I looked into `ssimval` function in MATLAB but it seems to be taking the whole image into consideration rather than just the white blobs. Is there any other function I can use for this purpose?

Comment: If you hope to get an answer, you must define what you consider "similar": aligned axes? size within 10% of each other? both are parallelograms? images have the same data type? Moreover, is "similar" a binary value, or is there a scale? Before you ask for help with implementation, it must be clear (both to _you_ and to _us_) what you're trying to implement.

Comment: To add to the last comment: You need to do this because there is not a universal definition of similar, neither in image processing or in the world in general. Defining the metric that best fits your objective is a key problem .

Answer (score 0):

For visually checking similarity, you can plot their **probability density function** and for numeric similarity, compute some similarity measure, such as, **KL Divergence**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way, you can segment your binary image with simple bwlabel function. Then use regionprops function to find perimeter and area of your desire segment. Moreover, center of region is also another comparison point.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with polygons, by using the polyshape class.

First convert the binary mask to a set of corner points. You can do it with a convex hull, by calling [regionprops(bwI, 'ConvexHull')](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html).

Then convert the corner points into polygons, by calling [polyshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.html).

Finally measure the dissimiliarities of the polygons by measuring their [turning distance.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.turningdist.html) Turning distance is rotation- and scaling invariant, so you might want to add additive terms to your distance metric for those if your problem demands it.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution for comparing two binary image is using boolean operations.

Your images contains zero and one values. so If you use boolean operation.

suppose your two images are :   B1 , B2

```
C = B1 & (~B2)


if sum(C(:))==0
    % two image are same
else
    % two image are different
end
```